# CMake Cannot link PostgreSQL Libraries

Tags: macos, postgresql, cmake

I need some help with PostgreSQL extensions in C

I have a little test-expansion to see if something doesn't work. 
It seems that cmake finds the Libraries but can only link GDAL to my project.
When building I get this error message:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug --target Project -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target Project
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.c.o
Linking C executable Project
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Float4GetDatum", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [Project] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Project] Error 2
```

main.c

```
#include <postgres.h>
#include <ogr_api.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {


    // GDAL Function compiles without errors
    OGRGeometryH g = OGR_G_CreateGeometryFromJson("POINT(0 0)");
    float4 f = 4.6;

    // Postgres Function doesnt work
    Float4GetDatum(f);

    OGR_G_DestroyGeometry(g);

    printf("%f", f);
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Project)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror")


set(PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server)
set(PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIR /usr/local/pgsql-9.1/lib)
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
find_package(GDAL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR} )


set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Project ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Project ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES} ${GDAL_LIBRARY} )
```

OS: Mac OSX 10.10.3
Postgres: 9.1.8

I´m using the CLion IDE.
Btw the Database itself works fine.

**EDIT:**
Output with verbose on

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug --target Project -- -j 2
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/Users/Max/Development/CLionProjects/Project -B/Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Project
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/Users/Max/Development/CLionProjects/Project -B/Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug/CMakeFiles 1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Project.dir/depend
cd /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug && /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/Max/Development/CLionProjects/Project /Users/Max/Development/CLionProjects/Project /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug/CMakeFiles/Project.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target Project
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Project.dir/build
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/Max/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/6306a90e/6306a90e/Debug/CMakeFiles 1
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.c.o
/usr/bin/gcc   -Wall -Werror -g -I/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers    -o CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.c.o   -c /Users/Max/Development/CLionProjects/Project/main.c
Linking C executable Project
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Project.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/gcc   -Wall -Werror -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.c.o  -o Project  -lpq -framework gdal 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Float4GetDatum", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [Project] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Project] Error 2
```

**EDIT 2:**

had "PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR= not found" in my Cmake Cache 
so I added `set(PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server/catalog)` to my CMakeList

CMakeCache

```
//Path to a program.
GDAL_CONFIG:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config

//Path to a file.
GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers

//Path to a library.
GDAL_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/Library/Frameworks/gdal.framework

//Path to a library.
PostgreSQL_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libpq.dylib

//Internal cache
 //Details about finding GDAL
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_GDAL:INTERNAL=[/Library/Frameworks/gdal.framework][/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers][v()]
//Details about finding PostgreSQL
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_PostgreSQL:INTERNAL=[/usr/lib/libpq.dylib][/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server][/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server/catalog][v9.1.8()]
//ADVANCED property for variable: PostgreSQL_LIBRARY
PostgreSQL_LIBRARY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
```

Comment: can you post the verbose output of the linking step to see which libraries are referenced? is your postgres installation a 64bit build?

Comment: added verbose output to the top ... yes it is 64bit

Comment: I don't see any `-L /usr/local/pgsql-9.1/lib` on the linker line. I'm wondering if it's finding Apple's `libpq` instead of the one for your version. Can you add the cmake variables file from the top level directory after running a build? (I've forgotten what it's called, ages since I used CMake)

Comment: added as asked to the top ... getting the same error

Comment: Maybe just a stupid comment, but have you considered the `find_package` function of CMake?